# htaccess with url rewriting not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/typo3$ - [L] RewriteRule ^/typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Obviously I want this URL:
www.example.com/username
to be translated to http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=username

This does not work however.. (this code results in the htaccess not working at all and getting a Page not found error.

If I change the ]+$ for a ]+? the code does work, but not like I want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/typo3$ - [L] RewriteRule ^/typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Results in the URL being rewritten/redirected to http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=index ... Exactly like that, so with user=index.

Now, if I remove the RewriteRule .* /index.php line, the htaccess again doesn't work at all anymore, resulting in a Page not found error...

I've spent days and days on figuring this out but I'm absolutely clueless..

So, I just want www.example.com/username to redirect to http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=username

Comment: I want to get the ID by simply matching the (unique) username... I See no other way. But the RewriteRules still don't work at my server. Really strange.

Comment: **get the ID by simply matching the (unique) username.** How is this matching be done?

Comment: By making a SQL query comparisson

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

- Inside a .htaccess file, patterns are matched ["against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). This means, you will have no leading slash as in `/typo3` or `^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?`
- The pattern `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?` matches also an empty request, because of the trailing `?`. I guess, this is not what you intended.
- Rules are processed in sequence, unless you do a redirect `[R]` or add an `[L]` flag. This is the reason why first the request is rewritten to `index.php` and then in the next rule `index` is recognized as the user and again rewritten to `.../index.php?id=82&user=index`
- Which leads to the next problem between the patterns `.*` and `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`. `.*` recognizes *all* requests, including every user. So there is no way to distinguish between a user and any other request.

---

To rewrite usernames, you could try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L]
```

This means, if the request doesn't correspond to an existing file `!-f` or directory `!-d`, then presume it's a username and rewrite to `index.php?...`.

If you don't want a redirect, leave out the host name

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Olaf for your comments. How would you suggest I write my code in order to achive what I need? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you distinguish a user name from another valid request?

Comment: That's a good question, and I wish I knew the answer to that..

The thing is, I need this functionallity: if a regular page or folder already exists, then don't rewrite the request, just show that folder or file (for ex.: www.example.com/admin  .. But when it does not exist, rewrite it to the user URL (/index.php?id=82&user=username).

Comment: So a valid request is always a physical file or directory?

Comment: BTW - Using www.example.com/users/username as a landing URL is also perfectly fine.. I'm just looking for a way to provide my users with a more friendly URL.. Instead of them having to type the ../index.php?id= thing..

Comment: So a valid request is always a physical file or directory: Normally yes